# Subsonic 3 and Linq Group by with Count

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

I have the following two tables:

```
Customer
{
int Id
int Name
}

Bills
{
int Id
int CustomerId
decimal Amount
bool IsDue
}
```

Now I am trying to get a list where I have:

1. A entry for every customer with the count of associated bills.
2. A entry for every customer with the count of associated bills where IsDue is true.

I tried doing the first one like this:

```
var results = from c in _db.Customers
              join b in _db.Bills on c.Id equals b.CustomerId into j1
              from j2 in j1
              group j2 by c.Id into grouped
              select new
                  {
                      CustomerId = grouped.Key, 
                      NoOfBills = grouped.Count()
                  };
```

This is throwing a error:
Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OutstandingMonitor.MonitorData.Customer]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[OutstandingMonitor.MonitorData.Customer]' ...

Please help me solve this.

Further, can both the queries be combined?

PS: Using Subsonic 3.0.0.3 with ActiveRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a not so efficient solution (if it is efficient indeed, I will love to know...:P). Here it is:

```
var results = from d in _db.Bills
          group d by d.CustomerId into g
          select new
          {
              CustomerId = g.Key,
              NoOfBills = g.Count()
          };

var results2 = from c in _db.Customers
           join r in results on c.Id equals r.CustomerId
           select new
           {
               CustomerId = r.CustomerId,
               CustomerName = c.Name,
               City = c.City,
               NoOfBills = r.NoOfBills
           };
```

For the time being it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you're using the value for the "customer's count of associated bills", can't you simply do this in LINQ (this will only work, however, if you have the appropriate relationships set up in the DBML):

```
var customers = _db.Customers; // Not necessary, but here for clarity

// ... more code

// Access the number of bills for each customer:

foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    int totalBills = customers.Bills.Count();
    int totalDueBills customers.Bills.Where(b => b.IsDue).Count();
}
```

Comment: I think you're referring to LINQ to SQL and he's using SubSonic.

Comment: Yes. And I am using SQLite. Is there any way to generate Foreign Key relations with SubSonic and SQLite?

Comment: @John - correct, I apologize for assuming LINQ-to-SQL, though I'm surprised something similar can't be done.

Comment: I managed foreign key relation generation using PRAGMA foreign_key_list. But still that doesn't help my cause.

Is this is a bug in SubSonic?